# Add breakpoints for all classes and all their methods in a project (Eclipse/debug)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I want to know if it's possible to create breakpoints for an unknown project in an easy way in eclipse with hundreds of java classes.

The reason: many times I need to work in a big project with no documentations at all nor somebody to explain.

So to maintain code, I need to know where the execution goes for every different functionality.

I want to know if there is a better solution as well.

(Debug step filtering is not that good for me as a solution).

Comment: have you tried to match all classes with a regex and add a breakpoint all at once? http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html